# Prevent user manipulation of site data through URL?foo=bar

Tags: php

My registration backend php redirects user to frontend like so:

```
header('Location:registrationView.php?warning='.urlencode($error));
```

on frontend I echo my variable which tells the user to completely fill the registration form like so:

```
if ($_GET)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["warning"]);
}
```

The thing is using get method like above if user decides to manually change URL which now looks like `http://localhost/registrationView.php?warning=Fill+complete+form` to something like:

```
http://localhost/registrationView.php?blahblah
```

or

```
http://localhost/registrationView.php?warning=blahblah
```

he of course either gets an error or he changes the text displayed on website to "blahblah"!

Is there a way to prevent this manipulation of URLs, or is there a better way to return warning messages from backends?

Comment: A good pattern for this is *flash messaging*. The basic concept is you store the message in session and clear it once it's been displayed

Comment: Ah yes sessions would be good for this sort of thing I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use session's for errors instead.

if an error is to be returned I usually do something like.

```
    $_SESSION["error"] = "my error text.";
```

I usually try to send them to a success page after they do something.

At the top of the success page I put something like this to redirect them back to the original page.

```
    if (!empty($_SESSION["error"])){
        header('Location: original_page.php');
    }
```

Then, in the original page I put something like this.

```
    if (!empty($_SESSION["error"])){
        echo $_SESSION["error"];
        $_SESSION["error"] = null ;
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
    }
```

This way they are displayed their error and no code could ever be executed if they start trying to type random things.

I never use $_GET for anything that could be manipulated.

Comment: well everything in $_POST and $_SESSION can be manipulated as well.  Especially if your talking about the developer.

Comment: I see the usefulness of sessions for my problem but what lets say if you must use get for bookmarking or maybe refreshing pages? Other than that I think sessions are better than get in any way

Comment: If your using get for bookmarking then your essentially saying you dont care if a person types that url in.  

For instance mysite.com/index.php?page=blog

who cares if they type that in if you want them to be able to book mark it?  Which is essentially the same thing as typing it in.

However, if you want to stop them from doing something like typign in mysite.com/index.php?page=admin  just add a function to your admin page that checks to see if the logged in user is actually admin.

Comment: Well is there any way to send data back to frontend without possibility of manipulation? What about using AJAX?

Comment: You can always stop them from manipulating data on your server.

But that problem should fix itself. Whats the purpose of your site?  Lets say your selling shoes.  If you have a user thats trying to break your site and typing random stuff into the GET fields.  They probably aren't trying to buy shoes from you.  Who cares if they ruin the experience for themselves?  Just as long as they dont ruin it for other people.

Users who are using your site correctly generally wont by typing things in the URL bar. So, you can just ensure your site is structured well so they dont "accidently" do that.

Comment: Stuff at the front end can ALWAYS be manipulated.  If a user is using your site for its purpose they wont do that.  If they aren't who cares what they see.  They caused it themselves.  This is more a social problem then a coding problem I think.

Comment: Thank you for extended answer! What is your take on using AJAX with XMLHttpRequest to display warning messages without reloading pages?

Comment: I'm not sure I have much of a take on it.  the XMLHttpRequest Object is really nice to use.  It would allow you to display error messages before the form was submitted.  So it could really reduce frustration on the user side.  (Especially if the developer didn't think enough to repopulate the form fields when an error is thrown.)

Comment: Why are you using `$_SESSION["error"] = null`? Isn't unset enough?

Comment: Generally, unset() is enough.  It has to do with speeds which one to use.  = null clears the memory now unset() will clear everything that = null didn't clear.  heres my results. http://pastebin.com/D8231n4B  I'm under the impression that you get your faster speed by using =null to process the rest of the script.  then you end up at the unset() speed as max.  Theoretically thats faster than just using unset().  But I cant think of any sources and  I'm not confident thats true.